# Virtualenv Python 2.4

Tags: python, virtualenv

When using virtualenv I find that the command: virtualenv -p python2.6 --no-site-packages ~/env/NEW_PROJECT  works without any problems, however if I try to do  virtualenv -p python2.4 --no-site-packages ~/env/NEW_PROJECT I receive the error "The executable python2.4 (from --python=python2.4) does not exist. Is there a way to setup a virtualenv with python2.4?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have Python 2.4 installed?  It looks like it's trying to find Python 2.4 but can't see where it is installed.

Comment: Have you tried to point a full python 2.4 path ?

Comment: Does `which python2.4` yield some result?

Answer (score 2):

You may not have `python2.4` installed or not in your `$PATH`.

`virtualenv`, different from `rvm`, does not install Python versions, it only uses what you have already installed. When you use `-p` option, that means `--python`, you are telling virtualenv to create a new isolated environment based on that Python installation.

So, if you have a Python 2.4 installation somewhere, just do:

```
$ virtualenv --python /path/to/python2.4/bin/python2.4 --no-site-packages ~/env/NEW_PROJECT
```

PS.: `--no-site-packages` is deprecated in new `virtualenv` versions. By default it does not use global site-packages.

Answer (score 1):

The support for `python2.4` was dropped in `virtualenv 1.8` therefore make sure you use `virtualenv<=1.7.2`.